# llvm without runtime gcc dependency?

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to minimize the number of old(er) GCC compilers I need to maintain on my systems and reduce implicit dependencies that I have to track (esp. w.r.t. LLVM)

I want to build a version of LLVM that (ultimately) is NOT dependent on the GCC that built it.  It should only be dependent on stuff within the LLVM install directory and default system tools/includes/libs, etc...  I'd like to not have a solution that requires a lot of makefile customizations, etc...

I'm on CentOS 7 or 8 and build a (newer) GCC in say /scr/gcc-11.3.0.  I then use that to build LLVM in say /scr/llvm-14.0.5 with GCC_INSTALL_PREFIX=/scr/gcc-11.3.0 and CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS based on /scr/gcc-11.3.0.  Everything works fine.

Now say GCC 11.4.0 comes out and I install it in /scr/gcc-11.4.0 and remove /scr/gcc-11.3.0 from my system (i.e. just maintain the last minor version).  From what I can tell my LLVM will now be broken (and maybe some of the applications I built with it?) It would be nice if there was a way to get the old LLVM to work off the newer (minor version upgrade) GCC but I'm guessing that's too much to ask.

I've seen discussions about building LLVM independent of GCC, and about bootstrapping LLVM with LLVM to achieve that but what I've found is not detailed enough for me to follow it.

The only solution I've come up with is to build LLVM with it's own copy of GCC (i.e. /src/llvm-14.0.5/gcc-11.3.0) but that seems like a kluge.

I would like to be able to support any of the "monorepo" versions of LLVM (which I think means back as far as LLVM 9) but I'll take what I can get.

Thoughts? Pointers?

Comment: So, the problem is that your newly-built LLVM depends on libstdc++, etc. that are provided by your custom gcc? Maybe you'd simply link them statically (via `-static-libstdc++`)?

Comment: He wants to have no dependencies, but does not specify what the concrete problematic dependencies are in the platform in question. Difficult to answer.